# Open Chrome with Toggle Device Toolbar Activated

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-devtools, headless, mobile-emulator

I'm working with java in Selenium, and I have to automaticed some tests, some how needs use Chrome Headless and Mobile Emulation. I know how to open chrome with "--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs" and with "mobileEmulation", but i need to open it with Toggle Device Toolbar activated. This mode, emulate the touch interactions events, replacing the click with a touch. How can i do start Chrome wiht this mode? (I´m using ChromeDriver v.2.358161)

Here's my code:

```
(...)
        Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Galaxy S5");
        ChromeOptions headlessOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        headlessOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, headlessOptions);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
(...)
```

What new argument i must to add?

(I made a robot press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> but this doesn´t works with Chrome Headless).

```
protected void pressModoResponsive() throws AWTException {
        pressF12();
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        waitSleep(1);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M);
        waitSleep(1);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_M);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    }
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: I´m working with Java in Selenium

Comment: My web driver version is  ChromeDriver 2.35.52816

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
I couldn't make WebDriver simulate a mobile device in selenium.

The workaround is being to add the argument:
`--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs`, then switch the device to mobile and leave the session saved with`--user-data-dir`